# Painting a custom Mouse over your preset mouse

Tags: java, awt, paint, mouse-cursor

I'm making a game and when I add my sprites to my screen, naturally, they are behind my mouse. But I want to add a custom mouse image to my screen, over the mouse.

I already have sprites for the mouse, and I know to to make the image appear wherever my mouse is. The only thing is that I already know its going to appear underneath my mouse. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image as a custom [`Cursor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html).  See [`Toolkit.createCustomCursor(Image,Point,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29) for turning the image into a cursor.

Comment: Sorry if question was difficult to understand. Tried being descriptive as I could, Thank you Andrew I wasn't aware i could set custom cursors, your answer defiantly pointed me in the correct direction. =D